# Can Transporter download screenshots from iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itmstransporter

I have successfully downloaded metadata for one of my apps from iTunes Connect using Transporter with the following command:

```
iTMSTransporter -m lookupMetadata -u <username> -p <password> -vendor_id myAppSKU -destination ./
```

This creates a new folder called myAppSKU.itmsp which contains a single file called metadata.xml.  Is there any way to force Transporter to download the screenshot assets for my application to the same folder or must I do this by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such functionality for the iTMSTransporter. (at least not yet)

Source: The Transporter User Guide and the fact that I've been dealing quite a bit with iTMSTransporter for a project.

Comment: With Film and TV, the transporter adds a `read_only_value` element with a URL pointing to the given asset, image, video, etc...This isn't the case with apps? Please let me know, I'd like to [add it to my program](https://github.com/sshaw/itunes_store_transporter#using-itms).

Comment: Nope, the lookupmetadata method only returns the metadata.xml without the screenshot files, and it only references the images by their filename (no URLs).

(by the way, great work on your project sshaw, I had looked it up for a bit although we ended up not using it :) )

Answer (score 0):

You can use [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools)'s [`deliver` tool](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/deliver/). It can not only *upload* your app, metadata and screenshots, but also download your metadata or screenshots.